# apache high system CPU time

Tags: apache-2.2, php, cpu-usage, munin

I have a web server: ubuntu apache+php app+postgresql
and a stats server: ubuntu apache+php - piwik and munin2 installed.

The communication for munin2 is made through ssh.

In munin i see a lot of system cpu activity, that I assume it it because of apache (i see 5 or 6 apache instances using ~5% CPU on top)

I was not having this system CPU activity before.

Does anyone knows how can I see where that comes from?

EDIT: some munin graphs
[image: munjin graphs]

Comment: You were not having this system CPU activity befor[e] *what*?

Comment: Leap Second Bug http://serverfault.com/questions/403732/anyone-else-experiencing-high-rates-of-linux-server-crashes-during-a-leap-second ?

Comment: good question... I don't know really, but I moved piwik to the other server, installed mod_pagespeed, installed curl (php app uses it a little). Maybe I did more thinks, not sure.

Comment: It might be that leap sec... not sure. I don't fully understand it. I'll attach munin graphs.

Comment: @Yohann Please make that comment an answer and I will accept it. I finally updated the kernel, rebooted, and it works all ok. Because of the date (as seen on munin graphs) I'll supose that the problem was that leap second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is considered a bug. See [Anyone else experiencing high rates of Linux server crashes during a leap second day?](https://serverfault.com/questions/403732/anyone-else-experiencing-high-rates-of-linux-server-crashes-during-a-leap-second)

Upgrading the kernel and restarting the system should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the TOP command to see system resource utilization.

```
#man top
```