# process ksoftirqd consumes permanent 15% CPU load

Tags: linux, debian, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anyone else experiencing high rates of Linux server crashes during a leap second day?](https://serverfault.com/questions/403732/anyone-else-experiencing-high-rates-of-linux-server-crashes-during-a-leap-second)

The process ksoftirqd/0 uses permanent 15% CPU on  our debian squeeze server.

```
4 root      20   0     0    0    0 R 15.0  0.0 850:59.17 ksoftirqd/0
```

I already read that this can have various reason like Full harddisk or high network traffic. In our case we do have more or less low network traffic and enough space on hard disk. How can I analyse what causes ksoftirqd/0 to use permanently 15% CPU?

Comment: It seems likely that you are experiencing the bug caused by the recent leap second. If not then please flag for reopening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ksoftirqd is taking a considerable percentage of CPU time that indicates the machine is under heavy interrupt load. This is one of the leap second problem symptoms , you might want to check:

[Anyone else experiencing high rates of Linux server crashes during a leap second day?](https://serverfault.com/questions/403732/anyone-else-experiencing-high-rates-of-linux-server-crashes-during-a-leap-second)

Comment: We have a flag / close reason for duplicate questions.