# why did i need to stop java software?

Tags: java, central-processing-unit, debian-squeeze, jenkins, elasticsearch

i am on Debian Squeeze, 4G of Ram, 1G of Swap, CPU i3 3.07GHz.
I used to use the following java softwares:

```
jenkins
elasticsearch
```

Problem was their process was too greedy about CPU, in the top command, each one was eating more than 120%.

When i noticed this, i switched from open-java to sun-java, but this did not do the expected trick.

I have a very little load on the server, but the over consumption of the CPU made the other processes go more slowly. (My web-stats for delivering pages show it clearly).

Since I have stopped elastic search, killed (the unstoppable) jenkins and then flush the cache memory, lighttpd regained its speed.

Any idea why these java processes can be so greedy ?
And why jenkins needs X11 although I don't need that at all ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When were you hit? Could it be the leap second problem that hit on both July 1st and recently on certain servers on August 1st, causing both Linux kernel crashes and Java CPU load problems? Here's [one of the main references for the July leap](https://serverfault.com/questions/403732/anyone-else-experiencing-high-rates-of-linux-server-crashes-during-a-leap-second), and a [thread about the August leap](http://lists.ntp.org/pipermail/questions/2012-August/033611.html).

Comment: yes, everything started on July 1st according to my stats. Now i'm struggling, the ntp stop ... ntpdate ... ntp start did work but don't seem to resolve anything

Comment: this did it : export LANG="en_EN"; date -s "`date`"