# Debian date jumping, causing complete lockup

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, date

I have a Debian Squeeze VM that has suddenly chosen to jump it's date forwards just over a month, which seems to confuse it no end and cause it to require a hard reset (yikes!).

There is nothing unusual in the logs, except that the datestamp suddenly jumps (today back to 2005).

It's happened three times, so I don't think it's to do with the [leap second issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/403732/anyone-else-experiencing-high-rates-of-linux-server-crashes-during-a-leap-second) as the last one of those was in July.

When it happened once I spent ages checking stuff but could not find anything, decided to forget it. But three times is becoming an issue on a production server.

---

Edits providing information requested in comments (thanks!):

I do not have control over the hypervisor, it is a hired VM.

```
# cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
kvm-clock

# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
+grendel.exizten 130.149.17.8     2 u   29   64   77   14.811    1.778   1.744
*panoramix.linoc 193.67.79.202    2 u   32   64   77   19.729   -0.419   1.691
+robert.elnounch 213.251.128.249  2 u   27   64   77   17.762    0.600   1.722
-janetzki.eu     83.169.43.165    3 u   31   64   77   27.214    3.575   1.638
```

Comment: Please tell more about the virtualization technology you are using and what clocksource you are using (``cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource``).

Comment: Thanks @gertvdijk, output of that is `kvm-clock`

Comment: Is a Vmware VM ?

Comment: Do you have control over the hypervisor? Are you running NTPd in the machine? If so, which servers is it listening to (``ntpq -p``)? @Sacx  no, it probably is KVM regarding the clocksource.

Comment: Does `dmesg` show something about changing the clock? Is there a difference with `date` and `hwclock`?

Comment: I think you should contact your hosting provider. Maybe a live migration is causing this or it is hitting a bug in KVM somewhere.

Comment: @ott-- nothing in `/var/log/messages`. `# hwclock -r;date` gives `Fri 23 Nov 2012 10:38:17 GMT  -0.997829 seconds` followed by `Fri Nov 23 10:38:18 GMT 2012` But note that the machine is up again now - can't test this when it's down for obvious reasons.

Comment: @gertvdijk have done, will report back if they find anything (they couldn't the first time)

Comment: It's definitely the host. If they change the date on the host, it passes through to the VM and causes your clock to go nuts. Since _they_ should be running ntp on the host, this is inexcusable. Find a better host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen several situations where NTP really doesn't like running in a VM.  One provider advised me to stop running `ntpd`, and instead have something like this in `/etc/cron.d/ntpdate`:

`* * * * * root /usr/bin/ntpdate your.ntp.server another.ntp.server > /var/log/ntpdate.log 2>&1`

This make the clock on my VMs much more stable, and stopped `ntpd` from doing the sync-unsync-sync dance.

If you do this, remember to put something appropriate in `/etc/logrotate.d` to stop the logfile growing indefinitely.